# TinyMCE custom addButton for fontsizeselect

Tags: tinymce-4

On TinyMCE using `fontsizeselect`in `toolbar`add a dropdown menu with font-size setted in `fontsize_formats: "8pt 9pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt"`. This dropdown has a **Fonts Size** label. I am looking for a way to create a custom button in toolbar for this dropdown by using `editor.addButton`but I am not able to load the font size in it.

```
editor.addButton('sizes', {
  type: 'menubutton',
  icon: 'myOwnIcon',
  ... 
    load `fontsize_formats` here
  ...
   });
```

Any help would be appreciated